# How to limit the minimum crop-able dimension of an image in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-intent, crop

There is quite a bit of talk about how to crop an image taken from Gallery or Camera. A very simple one, which not many people like, includes the following snippet

```
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 617);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 619);
```

(Anyway, the snippet is meant to be incomplete. Moving on...)

Notice how in the snippet I use two large prime numbers. I was here hoping to restrict the minimum crop dimension. 617X619 seems to have no effect, however; which to me basically means whatever algorithm is been used has such function similar to

```
double scale =  (double) aspectY/aspectX;
```

which is then used to match xDimen against yDimen.

But before throwing my hands in the air and giving up, I noticed that instagram has successfully managed to restrict the minimum dimension of the cropper. Does anyone know how I might accomplish this? Basically if you use instagram, you will notice that you cannot crop a "too small" portion of an image. How might I decide those dimensions?

Basically it's as if instagram is doing

```
  double scale =  (double) aspectY/aspectX;
  //....
  if(someInputX > aspectX){
    xDimen = someInputX;
    yDimen = scale* xDimen;
  }else{
    //do not crop any further
  }
```

I have been looking at a few cropping libraries to see if I can figure out how to fix the minimum dimensions, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have for example been studying the git projects linked to by http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: **Again** I am looking to limit the minimum size of the cropping rectangle, so that the user cannot take a very very small section of an image

Comment: What API level are you going for?

Answer (score 2):

Instagram has built their own cropping tool. If you are ready to build a cropping tool you can control anything. And it,s not that hard to build a simple cropping tool. If you have a good understanding of `MotionEvent` and how `Bitmap` works, it's 1 hour job for you.

Sample Code: Taken from [here](https://github.com/dtitov/pickncrop/blob/master/src/com/github/pickncrop/MainActivity.java)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imageView;
private ViewManager viewManager;
private Matrix matrix;
private int size;
private final int outputSize = 100;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    size = width < height ? width : height;
    size -= 50;

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCrop);
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = size;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = size;
    viewManager = (ViewManager) imageView.getParent();

    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)) {
        createZoomControls();
    }

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        float initX;
        float initY;
        float midX;
        float midY;
        float scale;
        float initDistance;
        float currentDistance;
        boolean isMultitouch = false;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initX = event.getX();
                initY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                isMultitouch = true;
                initDistance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(
                        initX - event.getX(1), 2)
                        + Math.pow(initY - event.getY(1), 2));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isMultitouch) {
                    matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
                    currentDistance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(initX
                            - event.getX(1), 2)
                            + Math.pow(initY - event.getY(1), 2));
                    scale = 1 + 0.001f * (currentDistance - initDistance);
                    midX = 0.5f * (initX + event.getX(1));
                    midY = 0.5f * (initY + event.getY(1));
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midX, midY);
                    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    imageView.invalidate();
                } else {
                    imageView.scrollBy((int) (initX - event.getX()),
                            (int) (initY - event.getY()));
                    initX = event.getX();
                    initY = event.getY();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                isMultitouch = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                isMultitouch = false;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void createZoomControls() {
    ZoomButtonsController zoomButtonsController = new ZoomButtonsController(
            imageView);
    zoomButtonsController.setVisible(true);
    zoomButtonsController.setAutoDismissed(false);
    zoomButtonsController.setOnZoomListener(new OnZoomListener() {

        public void onZoom(boolean zoomIn) {
            matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
            if (zoomIn) {
                matrix.postScale(1.05f, 1.05f, 0.5f * size, 0.5f * size);
                imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            } else {
                matrix.postScale(0.95f, 0.95f, 0.5f * size, 0.5f * size);
                imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
            imageView.invalidate();
        }

        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        }
    });
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoomLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    zoomLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    zoomLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageViewCrop);
    viewManager.addView(zoomButtonsController.getContainer(),
            zoomLayoutParams);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.info, 5).show();
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

public void buttonPickClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (resultCode) {
    case RESULT_OK:
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        imageView.setImageURI(targetUri);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        break;
    }
}

public void buttonCropClick(View view) throws IOException {
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "Pictures/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache(true), outputSize,
            outputSize, false).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
            fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
}
```

Be careful while processing high resolution images 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you open to using third party libraries? If so, you can use this one and change it so that it limits the minimum rectangle size (I don't believe it does allow that by default but it's easy to add it to the code if you really want to).

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper